# Ask for approval to change item column in Kanban in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, kanban

I am using VSTS and I want to achieve the following.
I have created a user story which currently is under a column in Kanban chart, Work->Backlogs page.
Is it possible to ask for approval when I try to change the column of the user story?
Or put a restriction so only authorized people to be able to change column.

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to ask for approval when I try to change the column of the user story?

No.

> Or put a restriction so only authorized people to be able to change column.

Also no.

Access restrictions can only be applied at the iteration/area path level, and they are all-or-nothing.

You can define [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/process/custom-rules?view=vsts) for work items, but those rules can't be applied to board columns, only work item field values (such as the state).

The best I can suggest is this, which is an awful, hacky work-around:

- Ensure your columns are directly mapped to states.
- Add a new field, "CanMove"
- Add a new rule for each work item state that clears "CanMove" *and* makes "CanMove" required

Now, every time you move the card between columns, it shows an error and doesn't actually transition until you open it up and set the "CanMove" field to some value. Personally, I would go crazy if I actually had to use that process.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I thought also so. your suggestions are useful.